# Lower Bound on Number of Edges in a Simple Graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory

Is there an expression for the lower bound of the number of edges in a Simple Graph with $V$ vertices, with $\deg (v) > m$ for all $v$?

Comment: Is there any restriction on the number of vertices?

Comment: Did you try the handshaking lemma?

Answer (score 1):

The number of edges is equal to the sum of the degrees divided by two.